# Angular: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

`

```js
company.ts file

 - List item

export class Company{
    gstNo:number;
    contactNumber:number;
    contactName:string;
    phoneNo:number;
    address:string;
    companyName:string;
}
```

[image: 1]

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase,AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
import{Company} from './company';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompanyService {

  private dbpath:'/register';
  companyRef:AngularFireList<Company>=null;
    constructor(private db : AngularFireDatabase){
      this.companyRef=this.db.list(this.dbpath);
    }
    createCompany(company:Company):void
   // postData(companyName:string)
    {
      
   this.companyRef.push(company);
   }
  /* private handleError(error){
console.log(error);

   } */
   
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div [hidden]="submitted" style="width :300px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 offset=md-1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 register-left">
            <div class="fon">

              <h3>Join Us</h3>
              <p>Helping people to make their lives easier is our mission </p>
              <i class="material-icons">
                  navigation
                  </i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-7 register-right">

            <h2>Register Here</h2>
            
             
            <div (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="register-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Company Name</label>
                <input ngModel name="company.companyName"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Address</label>
                <input ngModel name="company.address"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                 
                  <label>Phone No </label>
                  <input ngModel name="company.phoneNo" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="PhoneNumber">
                  
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
           
                  <label>Contact Person </label>
                  <input ngModel name="company.contactName"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                  <input ngModel name="company.contactNumber"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="MobileNumber">
                
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>GST No</label>
                <input ngModel name="company.gstNo"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Eg:12ABCDE1Z5">
              </div>
              <button  type="submit" (click)="postData()" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            
            <!-- <button (ngSubmit)="postData(companyName)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button> -->
        </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

  <div [hidden]="!submitted">
    <h2>Registration Completed!</h2>
    

  </div>

 
</body>


</html>
```

```js
 - List item

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CompanyService} from './company.service'
import{Company} from './company';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.scss']
 
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
 
  company: Company=new Company();
  submitted=false;
  constructor(private companyService:CompanyService){}
  ngOnInit() {
   
  }
  postData():void{
    this.submitted=false;
    this.company=new Company();
  }
  save(){
    this.companyService.createCompany(this.company);
    this.company=new Company();
  }
 onSubmit(){
   this.submitted=true;
   this.save();
 }
}
```

Comment: You should also be getting a file name and line number of where the issue is.

Comment: Your error is in company.service.ts line 12

Comment: you mean here (this.companyRef=this.db.list(this.dbpath);)

Comment: I have pinned an image of the error @HenslerSoftware

Comment: try to remove the slash from dbpath:'/register';

Comment: Any way Thanks!! @HenslerSoftware but still I'm stuck with same error **ERRoR** {TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at isFirebaseRef (utils.js:11)
    at getRef (utils.js:14)
    at

Comment: Is there any other method to push data in #firebase using #Angular

Comment: Do you mean adding a new record into a Firebase DB? Because your question was about an error and not about adding data. Your createCompany() function is empty.

Comment: yes @HenslerSoftware I need to add details from registration page to firebase realtime database Thanking you!! in advance

Comment: core.js:14597 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at isFirebaseRef (utils.js:11)
    at getRef (utils.js:14)
    at AngularFireDatabase.push../node_modules/@angular/fire/database/database.js.AngularFireDatabase.list (database.js:27)at new CompanyService (company.service.ts:12)
    at core.js:14397
    at _callFactory (core.js:19846)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:19804)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:19779)
 atNgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:20473)

Comment: Remove this.companyRef=this.db.list(this.dbpath); and see if you still get the same error. This error as explained earlier is to do with line 12 in your company,service,ts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your createCompany() function should look like the following:-

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {AngularFirestore} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {Company} from './company';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoggingService {

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
  ) {
  }

  createCompany(company: Company): Observable<any> {
    this.afs.collection('register').add(company).then((newCompany) => {
      return newCompany;
    }).catch((err) => {
      return err.toLocaleString();
    });
    return;
  }

}
```

Comment: after that i got this      @firebase/firestore: Firestore (5.8.0): 
  The timestampsInSnapshots setting now defaults to true and you no
  longer need to explicitly set it. In a future release, the setting
  will be removed entirely and so it is recommended that you remove it
  from your firestore.settings() call now.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1993#issuecomment-455830987

Comment: thanks!! but I have one more    ERROR Error: Function CollectionReference.add() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: a custom Company object
    at new FirestoreError (index.cjs.js:347)
    at validateType (index.cjs.js:635)
    at validateArgType (index.cjs.js:551)
    at

Comment: You should be able to find the solution at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/311#issuecomment-358982330